# Vue modules not found when importing in a Typescript file

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a Vue project that uses single file class component and typescript loader. I use VS Code with the Vetur plugin to get very nice code completion inside single file .vue components. This works fine except in my entry.ts file, where I create the root Vue component:

In entry.ts, I cannot import vue modules!

**index.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue'                       // this is ok
import App from './components/app.vue'      // vue file not found!
new App({el : '#app'})
```

`ERROR Cannot find module './components/app.vue`

**app.vue**

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue'                       // this is ok
    import Card from "./card.vue"               // here it works!

    export default class App extends Vue {
    }
</script>
```

From a `.vue` file, I **can** import other `.vue` modules.

I have tried leaving out the `.vue` extension, but that has the same result.

I have tried adding the `.vue` extension to a `.d.ts` file, but that messes up the Vetur plugin, and reverses the problem (modules only work from .ts files but not from .vue files)

Answer (score 6):

Hi Typescript gives you that error because It doesn't know what .vue file is.

But there's a work around for it.

In your project directory you can add a file called `vue-shims.d.ts`

Inside put the following code:

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}
```

Now typescript will understand .vue files.

Comment: Thanks, but that `.d.ts` file causes glitches with the Vetur plugin (which is needed to work with .vue files). intellisense becomes very glitchy and module paths are not recognised anymore in Vetur after I add the type definition file.

Comment: Even with this it doesn't work, it can't even import non-ts .vue files in. And it's selective, some files work, some don't.

Comment: If you uses Vue3, you have to import: `import type {DefineComponent} from 'vue'` and export `const component: DefineComponent<object, object, any>; export default component`